# Cannot connect to socket server on iOS?

Tags: ios, spring-websocket

I'm working on websocket on iOS platform using STOMPClient. Spring w/ sockJS on server side. This link works on browser, but not for iOS

http://172.16.0.229:8081/ineo-websocket?access_token=eyJraWQiOiIxZjB6eE5rS2VvVzJiMkhhRVdZSFBaNlBCRVJRa1p4VUF5bkUzRzB0UGg0IiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYifQ.eyJ2ZXIiOjEsImp0aSI6IkFULmN0YWYxVFhZVjU3TXA3Wk9PU0NNRUVLMC1JTkVsX2IwbzN2b2FNQXVQQ2suY3ZHNk5HUUtqOWJGRGEyMjlpRERvQXpGT0hCTVRFUU9UOWIwb3RUY2daND0iLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2Rldi00NDc1Njgub2t0YXByZXZpZXcuY29tL29hdXRoMi9kZWZhdWx0IiwiYXVkIjoiYXBpOi8vZGVmYXVsdCIsImlhdCI6MTUxNTc0NDcxNywiZXhwIjoxNTE1ODMxMTE3LCJjaWQiOiIwb2FkYmRhbW90R3AxSmlzZjBoNyIsInVpZCI6IjAwdWRpZWt2N29KbUc1Y1prMGg3Iiwic2NwIjpbIm9mZmxpbmVfYWNjZXNzIiwicHJvZmlsZSIsIm9wZW5pZCJdLCJzdWIiOiJ2aW5ocXVhbmcubHV1QG9mZmljaWVuY2UuY29tIn0.nhXLzoHCMYnWDdA6PHULDP6PG4Xg0vdZhfDPk0_GDuZCX0WPt1_2F67-z9rX34Ob82vvWdfS-Llpg26tFQ8Z6YxSZ0YT_yZmEYbEdPfpn3nIr4y9YBiHSddpkFypxvoEQ0m4Ko_I-JLQFXJ49e9X6Cedt7qN0SquVnpmonNej1YaYBSlYNbQAlS3_fpOd-qdXGMmF4JsKrpuRLl4fNC1wZAPU6TrGTRAsiz9yp6X-augI97kLzu9U4uRyJHLWLg-XVeTcwmiJ08tvlHvANDDGPmGTOFeguWAbwnohuhgKhd7IKt3dHqqukUbt1F7nZnEkNZWLjPj1AQdawF_SFKQPA

```
let client = STOMPClient(host: urlString, port: 8081)
```

What I get:

> SocketClient connect error: Optional("nodename nor servname provided,
>   or not known")

Could you point me what I'm wrong? Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: From the parameter names I'd say you should send your local IP as `host` parameter and somehow send the tokens, etc. in subsequent calls to client. Or perhaps there is a constructor from the URL...we need to know which STOMP client for iOS are you using.